# How can I generate cypress report files (.cucumber.json) for selected tags only?

Tags: cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Can anyone help me pls?

**1. I am running one scenario with two data choices:**

```
 @PM
 Feature: Product Move
 Scenario Outline: Example test
    Given I open Portal as admin
    And open 'Product Move' widget from 'Portal'
    And add products '<productName>'
      | Product       | 
      | <productName> | 

    @local @PM-01
    Examples:local
      | productName | 
      | example1    | 

    @int @PM-01
    Examples:Int
      | productName | 
      | example2    |
```

**2.After i run cypress test with special tag (@local):**

```
./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --env TAGS=\"@local\"
```

Cypress tests only the selected tag and skips others:

```
Product Move
    1) Example test (example #1)
    - Example test (example #1)

  0 passing (6s)
  1 pending
  1 failing
```

After that cypress generated .cucumber.json file in reports folder, but this file using **@int** tag

```
[
  {
    "keyword": "Feature",
    "name": "Product Move",
    "line": 2,
    "id": "product-move",
    "tags": [
      {
        "name": "@PM",
        "line": 1
      }
    ],
    "uri": "product-move.feature",
    "elements": [
      {
        "id": "product-move;Example-test",
        "keyword": "Scenario",
        "line": 49,
        "name": "Example test",
        "tags": [
          {
            "name": "@PM",
            "line": 1
          },
          {
            "name": "@int",
            "line": 28
          },
          {
            "name": "@PM-01",
            "line": 46
          }
        ],
        "type": "scenario",
        "steps": [
          {
            "arguments": [],
            "keyword": "Given ",
            "line": 30,
            "name": "I open Portal as admin",
            "result": {
              "status": "skipped"
            }
          },
          {
            "arguments": [],
            "keyword": "And ",
            "line": 31,
            "name": "open 'Product Move' widget from 'Portal'",
            "result": {
              "status": "skipped"
            }
          },
          {
            "arguments": [],
            "keyword": "And ",
            "line": 32,
            "name": "add products 'example2'",
            "result": {
              "status": "skipped"
            }
          ...
```

I guess cypress is overwriting the .cucumber.json file with the last unselected data. Because if I swap @int and @local example in the scenario, then @local data is displayed in the final .json file.
Could someone help me with this? In the future there will be more different environments.

How can I **generate cypress report files** (.cucumber.json) **for only selected tags** without overwriting?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Cytorus to run cypress tests using cucumber, you can freely manage reports by yourself.

```
const CucumerReporter = require("cytorus-reporter/cucumber");
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const paths = require('cytorus/paths');

async function generateReport(){
    const cucumerReportsPath = ".cytorus/reports/cucumber";
    if( fs.existsSync(cucumerReportsPath)){
        emptyDirSync(cucumerReportsPath);
    }else{
        fs.mkdirSync( cucumerReportsPath, { recursive: true});
    }

    // const sourcePath =  path.join(  __dirname, "../" ,paths.features ) ;
    const jsonDir =  path.join(  __dirname, "../" , paths.report.detailed);
    const cucumerReporter = new CucumerReporter(cucumerReportsPath, jsonDir, {
        screenshot: false
    });
    await cucumerReporter.report();
}

const emptyDirSync = location => {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(location);
    for (const file of files) {
        fs.unlinkSync(path.join(location, file));
    }
}

module.exports = generateReport;
```

This is the example from [cytorus bilerplate](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/cytorus-boilerplate). In above example, they're cleaning the repo before writing new reports. You can probably shift them to other folder.